# Apply fee for Paypal Payment only for a customer group

Tags: customer, paypal, group

i would like to apply a 3% Fee if customer selects Paypal as payment method and if customer is a reseller.
If the customer is a normal customer(and not a reseller) the fee should not be applied.
Have you got suggestions on how to do so? Could i start from an existing plugin?

Comment: See Similar to adding [a surcharge based on some conditions:][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33581/can-i-add-3-5-surcharge-fee-for-credit-card-payment

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-payment-fee.html If this helps in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1:
Here add module  which  is set extra free using http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-example

Step2:an  do some change

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);

    foreach ($this->_getAddressItems($address) as $item) {
            $this->_applyItemSurcharge($item,$address->getQuote());
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function _applyItemSurcharge($item,$Quote)
{
    $baseSurcharge = 0;
    if($Quote->getPayment()->getMethod()=='paypal_strandard' &&($Quote->getCustomerGroupId()=='reatialergroupcode')){

    $baseSurcharge =$address->getBaseGrandTotal()*3;
    }

    $surcharge = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($baseSurcharge);

    $item->setBaseCustomSurchargeAmount($baseSurcharge);
    $item->setCustomSurchargeAmount($surcharge);

    $this->_addBaseAmount($baseSurcharge);
    $this->_addAmount($surcharge);
}
```

Comment: Can i download a packed module somewhere? Would be easier to edit it. I'm new in Magento programming :)